# How do I apply the same VBA to all activex labels?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first time I use VBA.
I want to create simple checkboxes using Activex label (not using form label because then I wouldn't be able to edit the font, etc).
I use this code along with Wingding font:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    If Label1.Caption = Chr(254) Then
        Label1.Caption = Chr(168)
    Else
        Label1.Caption = Chr(254)
    End If
End Sub
```

I have multiple labels to act like checkboxes.
So I applied the code above to one label and copy paste that label.
However, the code did not adjust to the new labels' name.

How do I copy paste labels along with its vba?
Or is there a line of code that I can add to mine so that the vba refers to all labels in my worksheet, not just one particular label?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for such a purpose it was easier to handle `Form` labels. In such a case you could assign to all of them the same `Sub` and identify the object using `Application.Caller`...

In order to handle the ActiveX control you need a class:

1. Insert a **class module**, name it and paste the next code:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents lbl_Control As msForms.Label

Public Sub lbl_Control_Click()
    MsgBox lbl_Control.Caption ' you can do here whatever you want with the object...
End Sub
```

2. All labels for the sheet in discussion should be (somehow) initialized to use the above class for their `Click` event. So, please copy the next code in the `Activate` event or the respective worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private arrEvents As Collection, lblEvent As ClsLabels

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim shP As Shape

 Set arrEvents = New Collection

 For Each shP In Me.Shapes
    If shP.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
        If TypeOf shP.OLEFormat.Object.Object Is msForms.Label Then
            Set lblEvent = New ClsLabels
            Set lblEvent.lbl_Control = shP.OLEFormat.Object.Object
            arrEvents.Add lblEvent
        End If
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

3. Activate another sheet and go back to the one where labels in discussion exist, in order to trigger the `Worsheet_Activate` event.

Now, click on the respective labels and enjoy  the message...

Change their caption, **dezactivate - activate the sheet** and click on them.

In case of using `Form` labels, you should simple create a `Sub`:

```
Sub ChangeLBlCaption()
     MsgBox "Label name: " & Application.Caller
     Dim lbl As Label
     Set lbl = ActiveSheet.Labels(Application.Caller)
     MsgBox "label Caption: " & lbl.Caption
End Sub
```

Then, only assign this sub to all `Form` labels you need to return their name. It can be done automatically, too...

This second label type assures a more reliable handling for such a purpose. Since, in ActiveX case all labels must be reinitialized, from event class allocation point of view, after a VBA error and code stop, putting the label in Design mode to modify its caption (for instance) etc.

Comment: @matchbox13 Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, didn't it do what you need?